# Android - make toast or dialog inside static inner class of activity

Tags: android, android-context

I am having a problem getting the application context inside my **static** inner class:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
        .....
        ....

        public static class SMSAlertHandler extends BroadcastReceiver {
                @Override
                public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                    ....
                    ....
                    Toast.makeText(context, "this is my Toast message!!! =)",
                               Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            }
```

If I give context it is giving exception

> Unable to add window — token null is not for an application

Also if I put `getApplicationContext()`, showing error

> Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method
>   getApplicationContext() from the type ContextWrapper

Comment: Did you have the Application class? (extending Application)?

Comment: Is there any way you can make this BroadcastReceiver as a separate class instead of inner class?

Answer (score 2):

Yeap, static methods can't use references to non-static fields. And the context that you receive into your receiver is not allowed to make UI operations, you can take a look in [this article](http://possiblemobile.com/2013/06/context/) that shows up what you can do with each Context received.

You can set your receiver in the activity, like this:

```
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter("YourAction");
    registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
    // or LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(receiver, filter); if you are using LocalBroadcast system
} 



private BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
     @Override
     public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "message", LENGHT_LONG).show();
     } 
}
```

And a second approach (I'm not sure if will work because I didn't test yet) but in resume you get the context from the application class:

You can create a application class to get the context, example:

```
public class App extends android.app.Application {

    private static android.app.Application application;

    public static Context getContext() {
        return application.getApplicationContext();
    }

    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        application = this;
    }
}
```

Then you are able to use inside your receiver:

```
public static class SMSAlertHandler extends BroadcastReceiver {
   @Override
   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Toast.makeText(App.getContext(), "this is my Toast message!!! =)",
                               Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
   }
}
```

Remeber to add the App class into your AndroidManifext.xml

```
<application
        android:name=".App"
        ... >
```